# Jack Campbell: The Lost Fleet Beyond the Frontier continuation

Tags: the-lost-fleet

I have just reread all of the The Lost Fleet series and the first prequel book but I am curious if there will be a continuation of the Beyond the Frontier Leviathan? The way it leaves you hanging indicates that there should be more to come. Maybe the comic series that is coming will cover it?

Comment: Just to confirm, are you asking if there exists information that more works ill be written in the series?

Comment: thank you for that info. i can understand the pause and i did like the 1st book of the Genesis series

Answer (score 3):

The author said that he is taking a break from the series right now, but that *Leviathan* is not the end.

> After eleven books in *The Lost Fleet* and *Beyond The Frontier* in the last ten years, *Leviathan* marks not an end, but a pause point. I need time to figure out where to go next, how far forward to take the story, and what to explore that will involve new adventures and new challenges. (Besides, Black Jack really deserves a break.)
>   <sub>[jack-campbell.com](http://www.jack-campbell.com/)</sub>

In the interim, he will be writing *The Genesis Fleet*. From this I speculate that we will not see *The Lost Fleet: Beyond the Frontier - Book 6* until this prequel trilogy is completed. So roughly 3 years, given his past rate of publication.

> While I'm working on that, I'll be writing a new trilogy set in the *Lost Fleet* universe. *The Genesis Fleet* will be set centuries before the events in *The Lost Fleet*, showing the events, challenges, and people who led a bunch of fiercely independent star systems to first form the Alliance, as well as the first clashes between the Alliance and the expanding Syndicate Worlds.
>   <sub>[jack-campbell.com](http://www.jack-campbell.com/)</sub>

Comment: Thank you for the reply, and the information. The pause is understandable and the Genesis series is off to a good start, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Another new trilogy: https://jack-campbell.com/_series/lost_fleet_outlands/lost_outland_boundless.htm

On Admiral John "Black Jack" Geary may have saved the Alliance only to destroy it, in this thrilling and eagerly awaited continuation of the New York Times best-selling series.

Due Early 2021.